# Block Matrix Inversion in Wikipedia

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) provides two formulas for block-matrix inversion:

$$ {\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf {A} &\mathbf {B} \\\mathbf {C} &\mathbf {D} \end{bmatrix}}^{-1}={\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf {A} ^{-1}+\mathbf {A} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} (\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}&-\mathbf {A} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} (\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}\\-(\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}&(\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}\end{bmatrix}},$$

and

$${\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf {A} &\mathbf {B} \\\mathbf {C} &\mathbf {D} \end{bmatrix}}^{-1}={\begin{bmatrix}(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )^{-1}&-(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )^{-1}\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\\-\mathbf {D} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} (\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )^{-1}&\quad \mathbf {D} ^{-1}+\mathbf {D} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} (\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )^{-1}\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\end{bmatrix}}.$$

Is it true then that all of the following equalities are true?

\begin{align}\mathbf {A} ^{-1}+\mathbf {A} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} (\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}=&\;(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )^{-1}\\
-\mathbf {A} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} (\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}=&\; -(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )^{-1}\mathbf {BD} ^{-1} \\
-(\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}=&\;-\mathbf {D} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} (\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )^{-1} \\
(\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}=&\; \quad \mathbf {D} ^{-1}+\mathbf {D} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} (\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )^{-1}\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\end{align}

Comment: Fun exercise: Expand $\bigl(\mathbf {A} ^{-1}+\mathbf {A} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} (\mathbf {D} -\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\mathbf {B} )^{-1}\mathbf {CA} ^{-1}\bigr)(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} )$ and show that it is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $A,B, C, D$ are fixed.

By uniqueness of the inverse, yes, those expression are equal provided those terms involved indeed exists.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the inverses involved exist, both terms are equal. But, generally, only one of them is used because the inverse of at least one term involved does not exist. For example, for $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, the first formula cannot be used, but the second formula can be used to evaluate the inverse.

---

Note that both of these formulae cannot be used to evaluate $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$.